# React Native Android app stuck at splash screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app, of which Android part was running just fine 24 hours ago. Now, it cannot move after the splash screen. The only stack trace I can see in the android studio is -

```
08-31 18:52:48.897 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.507 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.547 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.591 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.643 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.689 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.744 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.792 25716-25716/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.845 25716-25716/com.techmagnates.edulil W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.895 25716-25716/com.techmagnates.edulil W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.962 25716-25716/com.techmagnates.edulil W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.techmagnates.edulil-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.techmagnates.edulil-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
08-31 18:52:49.987 25716-25716/com.techmagnates.edulil I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-31 18:52:50.037 25716-25716/com.techmagnates.edulil E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
```

What can be possibly happening here?

my dependecies look something like

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-iap')
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile (project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    compile project(':react-native-static-server')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-razorpay')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We were having the same issue, and so far the work around that we did in order to keep working is to unlinking the fbsdk `react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk`, and deleting all the references on MainAplication.java and MainActivity.java.

We are not sure about the real problem or solution but we certainly know that is fbsdk who is causing the problem.

Comment: Actually I did find solution later on, yes it is react-native-fbsdk which was installing some updated version of fb android sdk. How i resolved is by forcing it to pin a specific version. To do that just add 
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
        }
    }
to app level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Following [Mayank Baiswar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116612/react-native-android-app-stuck-at-splash-screen/52133102#comment91226182_52133102) it worked for me and my `android/app/build.gradle` is now like this:

```
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0' } }

dependencies {                                                                                        
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')                                                     
    compile project(':react-native-sentry')                                                           
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')                                                        
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')                                                     
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')                                                             
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')                                                            
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')                                                         
    compile project(':react-native-config')                                                           
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])                                          
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"                                          
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules                          
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'                                               
}
```